# Xamarin.ios Native Firebase push notifications

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I can't find any tutorial for Xamarin.iOS native, Android has a great one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin

Also, Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging is for Android Native but Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging is for Xamarin.Forms.iOS. The names of those packages don't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow but setup/usage is "kind-of" buried in the repo for this library, so...

> ...but Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging is for Xamarin.Forms.iOS.

- The `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging` nuget has no dependancy on `Xamarin.Forms`
- It is the binding for the native iOS `FirebaseMessaging.framework`

You should review the Firebase and the Xamarin docs for its usage:

Official Docs: [Setting Up a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)

Xamarin'*ized*™ C# Version: [GettingStarted](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/d7cb4c0f1c32701db41e6175c1483cdad2a97184/docs/Firebase/Auth/GettingStarted.md)

Comment: @MartinEvans Updated the link

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use that event directly on the **pcl project**, so you have direct access to your pages. You can handle it directly from your forms project.
2. You can use topic subscriptions for that. More info here: [Firebase Notifications](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/FirebaseNotifications.md)
3. You can do this on the `OnNotificationOpened` event handler:

   ```
   CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s,p) =>
   {
        //Your navigation code here
   };
   ```